# Flutter - SDK Error After adding Plugin in PubSpec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

AFter adding this plugin [image_editor_pro](https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor_pro) showing this error on getting package..

[memeistan] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in memeistan...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.4.

> Because image_editor_pro >=1.0.7 depends on cupertino_icons >=1.0.1
> which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, image_editor_pro >=1.0.7
> is forbidden.
>
> So, because memeistan depends on image_editor_pro ^1.0.8, version
> solving failed. pub get failed (1; So, because memeistan depends on
> image_editor_pro ^1.0.8, version solving failed.) exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Either you will try to find version that suits your sdk version, or you will update your dart sdk, or just add `image_editor_pro` package to dependency_overrides. Last solution may cause some issues so be aware.

Comment: my dark sdk i upto dated

Answer (score 0):

Use

> flutter upgrade

to update both your* Flutter and Dart SDK's

But your comment suggests your SDK is auto updated

So

You may need to look through the plugin docs and find which version of it can run with your current  SDK version